# C++ Qt QShortcut with numpad key

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

[QShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html) makes it easy to connect a QShortcutEvent (Key press, combination or sequence) to a slot method, e.g.:

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut( QKeySequence(Qt::Key_7), this, 0, 0, Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
```

(Hint: for number keys, a QSignalMapper can be used to map the QShortcut's `activated()` signal to a Slot with `int` parameter).

However, in this example, with NumLock ([numpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad) enabled), both '7' keys will trigger the Shortcut's `activated()` signal.

Is there a way to detect the different keys other than filtering or reimplementing a widget's [keyPressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) and check [QKeyEvent::modifiers()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#modifiers) for [Qt::KeypadModifier](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum)?

Digging further, I found

[QTBUG-20191 Qt::KeypadModifier does not work with setShortcut](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-20191) linking to a [patch that has been merged into 4.8 in Sept. 2012](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/15188/2/src/gui/kernel/qshortcutmap.cpp) and which comes with a [test case](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/15188/2/tests/auto/qpushbutton/tst_qpushbutton.cpp) using

```
button2->setShortcut(Qt::Key_5 + Qt::KeypadModifier);
```

which does not work for my QShortcut on Qt 4.8.1, i.e. neither of the '7' keys are recognized using (adding) the modifier flag.

So I guess the quickest way would be installing a filter to detect the modifier and let all other keyEvents be handled by the default implementation to be useable with QShortcut?

Comment: your solution seems best. I reimplement keyPressEvent()/keyReleaseEvent() most of the time and just filter there.

Comment: quickest way — is to install an event filter for another object. An event filter gets to process events before the target object does, allowing it to inspect and discard the events as required

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Qt.KeypadModifier`, For example [Python]:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    numpad_mod = int(event.modifiers()) & QtCore.Qt.KeypadModifier
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key5 and numpad_mod:
        #Numpad 5 clicked
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use [keyReleaseEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyReleaseEvent)(QKeyEvent *event)
For example

```
void Form::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)    {
    int key = event->nativeScanCode();

    if( key == 79 ) //value for numpad 7
    {
       //your statement   
    }


}
```